# How to fit TT brake levers

Tags: maintenance, brakes

got a set of profile design bull horns and fitting an aero lever/tt brake.

name this one [image]

how is this inserted into the handlebar and how does one adjust?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are generally inserted in the location where the bar end plus would go. Most if not all of these levers have a rubber plug at the front that you remove to reveal a bolt that you will need to turn to tighten itself onto the inside of the handle bar.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the brake cable?

You could use an inline adjuster.

[image]